# DrawerLayout on click disabled after first event

Tags: android, onclick, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I'm trying to implement a drawer layout in my app. I follow the tutorial on android developer site and all goes fine. I have only a "little" problem: I lunch the app, open the drawer layout and click on an element of the list view and all goes great, but when I try to open another time the drawer and click on one of his element I noticed that the element that I've first clicked is still clicked and i'm not able to click on any of the other elements.The drawer simply close without lunching any onClick events.
My code is:
    public class Eventi extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

```
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mPlanetTitles;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.eventi);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
    // opens
    // mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
    // GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.listview_item, mPlanetTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
    mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
    R.drawable.ic_launcher, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
    R.string.hello_world, /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
    R.string.hello_world /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.eventi, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content
    // view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action buttons
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        // create intent to perform web search for this planet
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
        // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.hello_world, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        System.out.println("c2");

        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    System.out.println("c");
    final String[] classes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.classi);
    FragmentTransaction tx = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    tx.replace(R.id.drawer_layout,
            Fragment.instantiate(Eventi.this, classes[position]));
    tx.commit();
    /*
     * // update the main content by replacing fragments Fragment fragment =
     * new PlanetFragment(); Bundle args = new Bundle();
     * args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
     * fragment.setArguments(args);
     * 
     * FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
     * fragmentManager.beginTransaction() .replace(R.id.content_frame,
     * fragment).commit();
     */
    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

}
```

I took it from the Developer site so I don't understand wher is the error. Is there anyone who can help me?
Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at my code:

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

private void selectItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {

            case 0:

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, new MainActivityFragment())
                        .commit();
                break;

            case 1:

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, new DbListViewFragment())
                        .commit();
                break;

            case 2:

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, new StatisticsFragment())
                        .commit();
                break;

            case 3:

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, new CalculatorFragment(), "calculator")
                        .commit();
                break;

        }
```

I am using a switch-case. position 0 is the very first item in my ListView inside the drawer.

Comment: I don't understand what wrong  I was doing but your code works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using

```
                                   FragmentTransaction.replace(r.Id.drawer_layout,fragment).
```

don't attach a fragment directly to the drawerlayout element , try to add a framelayout as your main content container then attach the fragment to this framelayou.
Your xml content should look like this sudo one

```
<drawerlayout>
    <framelayout Id:fragment_holder/> //attach fragment        to this view
        <ListView/>  // your drawer ListView.
<drawerlayout/>
```