# Switching entire fragments in NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was working my way through the NavigationDrawer sample code from developer.android.com and tried to implement it as navigation for one of my apps. However, I came across a problem when it came to switching fragments in the main window, as the sample code reuses the same fragment and just switches out an imageview. Here is the code from the sample:

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

where PlanetFragment is a generic fragment with only an imageview and no functionality, which does not apply for my app. So, instead, I tried and replaced the first block of the selectItem method with a case/switch:

```
public void selectItem(int position){
Fragment fragment;
switch(position){
    case 1: fragment = new Fragmentscreentest(); break;
    case 2: fragment = new Fragmentstatusbar(); break;
    case 3: fragment = new Fragmentfullscreen(); break;
    default: fragment = new Fragmentscreentest(); break;
}
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

and added the same empty constuctor to my Fragments as the PlanetFragment has:

```
public Fragmentstatus() {
    // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
}
```

It doesn't work, whenever I open up the app, it only shows the app icon and the title in the actionbar, no content, no actions on the actionbar, no navigation drawer, nothing and then it crashes after about a second. With the original code it works and shows everything, but that only works for one fragment.

How can I actually switch Fragments in the NavigationDrawer?

Comment: Post the stack trace of the crash from your logcat.

Comment: Thanks, already fixed, The answer from mike.b93 and fixing an unrelated bug worked out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at my code:

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

private void selectItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {

            case 0:

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, new MainActivityFragment())
                        .commit();
                break;

            case 1:

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, new DbListViewFragment())
                        .commit();
                break;

            case 2:

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, new StatisticsFragment())
                        .commit();
                break;

            case 3:

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, new CalculatorFragment(), "calculator")
                        .commit();
                break;

        }
```

I am using a switch-case. position 0 is the very first item in my ListView inside the drawer.

Taken from my answer on this question: [DrawerLayout on click disabled after first event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107424/drawerlayout-on-click-disabled-after-first-event/17108058?noredirect=1#comment24797849_17108058)

EDIT:

If you want to select one Fragment at start you can do it like this at the end of your onCreate method:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
```

0 being the position of your desired Fragment

Comment: Thanks, this and fixing an entirely unrelated bug in my script did the trick for me. I would upvote, but can't due to my status as a new user, accepted the answer though.

Comment: @MarcelUlbrich glad to help, feel free to upvote as soon as you're allowed to :D